# Changing default code in catch-Block of an auto-inserted exception block in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When a method, which throws any Exception is called without a surrounding try/catch-block, IntelliJ gives a warning and provides a feature which inserts such a surrounding try/catch-block. The default inserted-code looks like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (...Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is it possible to adjust the code in the catch-block somewhere?
So, for example, instead of `e.printStackTrace();`, it would write `MyLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be modified in Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Catch Statement Body.